# How to save image from rich text editor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, richtextbox

I have a form including rich text editor in it.

While with only content in richtext editor I don't get any problem in saving it in database.
But when I attach an image in it, It always pokes me with this error-

```
Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.
```

Yes the URI is absolutely so long, But why don't this form saves it even if I had given datatype to `nvarchar(MAX)` to be saved.

See in pictures-

[image]

and URI of this image -

[image]

While model type has `nvarchar(MAX)` datatype for this rich text editor.

I am performing simple save function and rendering rich text editor's values by

`@Html.Raw()` helper.

For this editor's rendering I am doing this on client side-

```
 @Html.Raw(Model.businessDetails)
```

**Model-**

`public string businessDetails{get;set;}`

Why SQL SERVER doesn't save this long uri? What went wrong in my form submission?

Comment: Do you pass the values in query string ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first thing first,

you should be doing this as a POST request not as a GET!

after that you have two options

**1)**

set an attribute so it will [allow HTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) in the string and it will store the image as base64 in the html and you won't have to worry about storing it anywhere.

```
[AllowHtml]
public string businessDetails{ get; set; }
```

**2)**

1. grab the src of the image
2. remove the `data:image/png;base64,` from it
3. decode the result with base64 converter , the resulting is binary result
4. ```
   byte[] imageArr ;

   //set your imageArr here---

   BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
   bi.BeginInit();
   bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
   bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.Default;
   bi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(imageArr);
   bi.EndInit();

   Image img = new Image();  //Image control of wpf

   img.Source = bi;
   ```
5. save image to destination. `img.Save("path",`[ImageFormat.Jpeg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)`)`
6. replace the src of that image with an actual URL